# Java search index in folder

Tags: java, indexing, webserver

I've wrote a little Webserver app. Now I have the problem, that I don't now how i can display index files. How can I get the first file in directory which starts with index? No matter which file extension. I get the dir with `new File("Path/To/Dir");`.

Please help me!

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `File#list()` method.

```
    // your directory in which you look for index* files
    File directory = new File(".");
    // note that indexFileNames may be null
    String[] indexFileNames = directory.list(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.startsWith("index");
        }
    });
    if (indexFileNames != null) {
        for (String name : indexFileNames) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
```

This will find all files which names start with `index` prefix.

Please note that `list()` method returns names of both files and directories. If you only need files, you can augment the `FilenameFilter` logic.

To get the first of these files, you need to define some order. For example, if you need to sort files on their names alfabetically (in case-sensitive manner), you could do the following:

```
    if (indexFileNames != null) {
        // sorting the array first
        Arrays.sort(indexFileNames);
        // picking the first of them
        if (indexFileNames.length > 0) {
            String firstFileName = indexFileNames[0];
            // ... do something with it
        }
    }
```

You could also sort with some comparator if you need some special order:

```
Arrays.sort(indexFileNames, comparator);
```

Yet another way is to avoid sorting and use `Collections#min()` method:

```
if (indexFileNames.length > 0) {
    String firstFileName = Collections.min(Arrays.asList(indexFileNames));
    // ... process it
}
```

`Collections#min()` also has a version with `Comparator`.

Comment: And how I can get the first of them?

Comment: I've updated the answer with additional information on picking the 'first' element